# Find the number of stars between two bars in a string - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I was given a String `S='&|&&|&&&|&'` where we should get the number of stars between two bars in the given string. 
So the output here should be 5. And here's my code:

```
Lis=[x for x in range(len(S)) if S[x]=='|']
min_idx=Lis[0]
max_idx=Lis[-1]
count_of_stars=S[min_idx:max_idx].count('&')
```

The problem I faced was my code was getting timed out for larger inputs in a coding platform. can anyone suggest a better way to reduce the time complexity here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to strip and count:

```
S='&|&&|&&&|&'

print(S.strip('&').count('&'))
```

Comment: It can be useful to add that this works only if the string is formed only of the characters `'|'` and `'&'`, otherwise `strip` would not have the intended effect.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following regular expression with lookaheads to match `&` only between bars:

```
import re
S = '&|&&|&&&|&' 

len(''.join(re.findall(r'(?<=\|)(\&+)(?=\|)', S)))
# 5
```

Where:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=\|)(\&+)(?=\|)', S)
# ['&&', '&&&']
```